Question on dominating convergence theorem
On $[0,1]$ we have sequence of non-negative continuous functions {${f_n}$ } converging pointwise to $f(x)$,
and $f_n(x)\leq f(x)~\forall~x\in[0,1].$
Is this condition enough to conclude the following equality?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{f_n}dx=\int_{0}^{1}{f}dx.$$
I thought of using dominated convergence theorem but couldn't prove that $f\in L^1[0,1]$.
Alternatively, I am thinking to construct an increasing subsequence by using the condition $f_n(x)\leq f(x)$ and then apply monotone convergence theorem, but then to prove the full result I would have to prove that left hand side of the above result converges.

Use Fatou’s lemma for one of the inequalities, and $f_n\leq f$ for the other; in fact this way we even prove the existence of the limit on the LHS. Note that we may not have $f\in L^1([0,1])$, but that’s fine.

$f_n(x)=n^{2}x$ for $x <\frac 1 n $ and $\frac  1x $ for $x \geq \frac 1 n$ shows that $f$ need not be integrable.

@peek-a-boo i didn't see how limit exist on left side, it is only lim-inf.

Yea Fatou’s lemma only tells you about liminf. Then like I hinted at, $f_n\leq f$ tells you $\limsup\int f_n\leq \int f$. Put these two remarks together.

@peek-a-boo ok got it. and i already have a natural inequality to conclude final result
